# Does ibm worklight context not get lost during routing of angular js

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, angularjs-routing

we normally use window.location.href or link to href for changing the url while routing..does the worklight context get lost while changing the url with the #

Answer (score 0):

Worklight apps are single-page apps. You **must not** change location using window.location.href, links or alike - by doing so you will lose the Worklight context and the application will fail to properly work.